# How to set up NSPredicate to exclude selection based on presence in an array?

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cncontact

I am setting up an app which allows a user to select a particular contact from their contacts. It is set up (and works) as follows:

```
let contactStore = CNContactStore()

var contactArray = [CNContact]()

func selectContact(){ //This is called upon the tapping of a UIButton

    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey]

    contactPicker.delegate = self

    contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count >= 0")

    contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count >= 1")

    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    contactArray.append(contact)
    print(contactArray)
    contactsTableView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true)

}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    contactArray.append(contactProperty.contact)
    print(contactArray)
    contactsTableView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Now, again, like I said the code works fine. However, after the user selects a contact, and therefore adds it to the `contactArray` I would like that contact to no longer be selectable when they open the `contactPicker` the next time the button is pressed. I know *what* I need to do (modify the `contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact`), but I do not know *how* to do it to achieve my desired result. I had been following [the ContactUI framework tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/223/) here and they achieved the desired result by making the predicate: `NSPredicate(format: "(phoneNumbers.@count >= 1) AND NOT (identifier IN $@), self.buddies.map{ $0.identifier }")`. `buddies` in their example, though, is not an array of `CNContacts` as my array is, and so transferring this code directly over to mine did not work and yielded an error. I do not really understand predicates (and definitely not the `$0.` kind of thing), so I am very lost on how to define my predicate.

Comment: `self.buddies` is an Array of `CNContactProperty`. ``self.buddies.map{ $0.identifier }` is the "same as" (in pseudo code): `let arrayOfIdentifiers : Array.new(), for (acnContactProperty in self.buddies){arrayOfIdentifiers.append(acnContactProperty.identifier)}` and `arrayOfIdentifiers == self.buddies.map{ $0.identifier }`. I'd go by doing the same: Keep an array of `CNContactProperty` instead (it has more information than a `CNContact`) and do the same. In your TableView, instead of doing `contactArray[indexPath.row]`, do `(contactArray[indexPath.row] as CNContactProperty).contact`

Comment: @Larme I can follow your logic but if I use a `[CNContactProperty]` instead of `[CNContact]`, how do I handle `didSelect contact` picker function? How do I append the `CNContactProperty` from the `CNContact` that gets selected?

Comment: `didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty`: `contactPropertyArray.append(contactProperty)` with `var contactPropertyArray = [CNContactProperty]()`

Comment: @Larme yes I recognize that with the `didSelect contactProperty`. I was asking about the `didSelect contact` function they used (and that I have in my example code). Is there a way to get the `contactProperty` from the selected `contact`?